# How to enable Drag & Drop for all the children controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop, dockpanel-suite

My situation is as follows, I have win-forms applications with [DockPanel Suite](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) and lots of controls, which cover the entire screen,

I want to enable D&D of files from the windows explorer to the application. I know how to implement the D&D, but it seems that if i enable it for the main parent form, only the applications title-bar and task-menu icon reflect the change in the D&D.

I want the entire form to accept the files from the explorer. Do i have to enable D&D of files for each top control displaying in my application?

I am sure there is a better way to implement this, help?

**Clarify**

When a user drags files from the windows explorer to my form, I want every place in the form to give a feedback for such an event. Much like you can drag a file from the explorer to the Visual Studio, and it doesn't matter to where you drag it, the application accepts the file.

Comment: I deleted my answer/comments, feeling I should have made comments only. In VS 2010 beta 2 : dragging a .cs file from "outside" : you can drop only on VS Solution Explorer or on VS window itself. Anywhere else you drag : you just get a "can't drop here" cursor.

To make every control on your app give some dragover feedback is, I think, going to require either elaborate setting of event handlers recursively for every control on your form, or some incredible hack like a transparent window over the form when the form gets a drag-enter (and I'm not sure that would work , either). best,

Comment: i think your response is a good answer, i recommend you undelete it

Answer (score 0):

I've not used DockPanel suite, but with Visual Studio form designer creating form drop enabled and appropriate handers on the form, almost everything I add (no properties changed) allows the form to "see" the drag/drop. Including, Panel, SplitContainer, TabControl, ListBox, Button, ListView. The only thing I tried that didn't work (and the question I had when I arrived at this page) was the RichText control, I guess that's because it allows Drag-n-Drop editing.

My guess would be this is DockPanel suite specific behaviour. I don't know anything about that, but I'd guess it has to consume drag-n-drop to implement its dock functions. Maybe there are events you can hook at the DockPanel panel level rather than the form level.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using components from DevExpress, but managed to solve it by making sure all user controls had `AllowDrop = false` set. Basically, run a search for `AllowDrop = true` on the solution and make sure ONLY your main form has it set (you can remove all such lines from all affected designers since `false` is the default value.

This allows me to have one place that handles all drag/drop operations.